# Isn't there an event after the User is logged in in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, events, authentication

I want to write some data into the user session **after** the user has logged into my asp.net web application. But there doesn't seem to be a proper event for that.
I tried the `LoggedIn`event on my `Login.aspx.cs` but `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false`at that moment. I know that this is default behavior and after that the flag is set to `true`, e.g. after redirecting.
So is there a proper moment when to do this?

Comment: Think about what "logging in" means (also avoid, `WebControls`). Please tell us more about how you actually authenticate users. Are you using the `Membership` functionality or doing something more custom?

Comment: I use straight `asp:Login` with a custon `MembershipProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, ideal way will be to use `LoggedIn`.

Inside `LoggedIn` method, you can retrieve `UserName`.

The reason `IsAuthenticated` is false because, `IPrincipal` object hasn't been created yet. However, you can create it inside `LoggedIn` method by yourself.

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" OnLoggedIn="LoginUser_LoggedIn">
...
</asp:Login>

protected void Login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var username = LoginUser.UserName;

    // Log user
    .....

    // If you really want to create IPrincipal object, you can create like this -
    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
    Context.User = principal;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = Context.User;
}
```

Here is an example for [creating Principal object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.aspx).

*Note: I don't know the reason behind why you want to check `IsAuthenticated` inside LoggedIn event. Normally we do not need to create Principal object by ourself.*

Comment: Well I know that my scenario is some kind of bending the framework. But nevertheless your solution and explaination is good and works. So thx.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a check in the `Page_Load` of the location where your `Login.aspx` redirects from, like this:

```
Page_Load of Home.aspx: I made up Home.aspx, but that is a common landing page name
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Write into session here
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, I already was at that point. Problem is that the data is written into the session everytime the user calls that landing page, e.g. by refreshing.

Comment: I understand, but aren't you checking to see if people are authenticated on your page loads?

Comment: You can also check to see if the `Session` value already exists and if it does then skip writing to `Session` again.

Comment: Your last suggestion was also my last thought. So if there is no better solution I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is an OnAuthenticateRequest event that can be handled from Global.asax.  You just have to add an HttpModule for it.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzd570s(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzd570s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

updated:
I have not tried this but it's supposed to be a solution for your situation.
http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030211.asp

Comment: Unfortunately at this point the `Session`is `null` and I cannot write data into it.